# MySQL - Multi-table select

Tags: mysql

Okay. So here's what I'm trying to do.

products_description:
products_name | products_id

products_to_categories:
products_id | categories_id

categories_description:
categories_id | categories_name

Basically I want to get products_name where categories_name equals 'Refurbished' (which yields multiple rows). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT p.product_names

    FROM products_description p, products_to_categories pc, categories_description c

    WHERE p.products_id = pc.products_id

     AND pc.categories_id = c.categories_id

     AND c.categories_name = "Refurbished"
```

Comment: And suddenly I understand how aliases work. You are a god amongst mortals. Thank you. =)